# Использование команды mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь освоить использование команды mysqldump
Ввожу следующую команду:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> mysqldump -u alex -p 1 publications > publications.sql;
```

Но вместо ожидаемого результата получаю ошибку:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u alex -p 1 publications > publications.sql' at line 1

Кто-то может подсказать что я делаю неверно?

Comment: Как следует из книги по которой я занимаюсь:

"However, before you can dump the contents of a database, you must make sure that
mysqldump is in your path, or that you specify its location as part of your command."

Так вот, как я могу задать путь к программе mysqldump в комманде mysql? Какой должен быть синтаксис? К сожалению пояснений в книге нет(

Comment: `mysqldump` - не SQL команда, выполните её из обычного шелла.

Comment: Ок, но как это сделать? В книге об этом ни слова. Шелл это командная строка? Если да, то вот что выходит:

C:\>xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u alex -p1 publications > publications.sql
Отказано в доступе

Comment: Да, командная строка. С отказано в доступе загвоздка в том, что вы выполняете команду из корневого C:\ и соответственно пытаетесь записать файл `C:\publications.sql` - без запуска из-под администратора это не выйдет. Войдите в другой каталог (`cd другая\папка`) и выполните команду оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой командой попробуйте:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppassword --default-character-set=UTF8 --databases --quick databasename | gzip > `date +/var/db_backup/test/my_db.sql.%Y-%m-%d.%H%M%S`.gz
```

user - имя пользователя, имеющего доступ к БД

password - пароль для доступа к БД (внимание! пароль пишется слитно с буквой "p"!)

databasename - название БД

Comment: для экономии места и удобства дампы можно сразу архивировать и давать им имена по маске текущей даты и времени, чтобы потом отличать друг от друга